# When calling a class method in another file do we have to provide the value for self?

Tags: python, methods, parameters

I am trying to call a method from another file into another file and it has been imported but when calling it says that self parameter is not defined. Am a beginner programmer, need help :(.

Class:

```py
class ArithmeticMethod:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Arithmetic Class Init.')

    def addition(self, value1, value2):
        answer = int(value1) + int(value2)
        return answer


    def subtract(self, value1, value2):
        answer = int(value1) - int(value2)
        return answer


    def multiply(self, value1, value2):
        answer = int(value1) * int(value2)
        return answer


    def divide(self, value1, value2):
        answer = int(value1) / int(value2)
        return answer
```

The calling:

```py
from arithmetic import ArithmeticMethod

print(ArithmeticMethod.addition(value1=10, value2=9))
```

ERROR:
No value for argument 'self' in unbound method callpylint(no-value-for-parameter)

Comment: Please copy paste the code, instead of posting images.

Comment: @Amen Please edit your post to include the code. Do not send it in the comments, as it'll be unreadable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with files. You get the exact same behaviour when running ``ArithmeticMethod.addition(value1=10, value2=9)`` in the file that defines ``ArithmeticMethod``. Can you clarify why you define the operations inside a class, which implies an instance ``self``, when the operations do not actually need this instance?

Comment: There's no really reason to define this as a class in the first place. You simply have 4 regular functions (which are all defined in the `operator` module, by the way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```py
def addition(self, value1, value2):
    result = int(value1) + int(value2)
    return result
```

You're saying that the `addition` method is tied to an instance (due to `self` being the first argument). Thus, when you call it, you have to construct an instance to call it:

```py
myArith = ArithmeticMethod()
print(myArith.addition(1, 2))
```

Now, obviously, this is silly as you don't need the instance for anything and the `self` parameter is unused. So, get rid of it and annotate it with `@staticmethod`:

```py
@staticmethod
def addition(value1, value2):
    result = int(value1) + int(value2)
    return result
```

Now, you can call it as a static method without going through an instance:

```py
print(ArithmeticMethod.addition(1, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks but then this error occurs: Method should have "self" as first argumentpylint(no-self-argument)

Comment: @Amen I've edited the post to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Ah I see a decorator. Much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, the better approach seems to not have a class in the first place. The ``arithmetic`` module should directly contain an ``addition`` *function* (etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Name the file `arithmetic.py`

And just define the methods, all are static to the class and not related to the class

```python
def addition(value1, value2):
    return int(value1) + int(value2)

def subtract(value1, value2):
    return int(value1) - int(value2)

def multiply(value1, value2):
    return int(value1) * int(value2)

def divide(value1, value2):
    return int(value1) / int(value2)
```

Use it with:

```python
import arithmetic

a = arithmetic.addition(3,6)
```

Or

```python
from arithmetic import addition

a = addition(3,6)
```